# Invoke Lambda with terraform - permissions

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to invoke an AWS function that I am creating using Terraform (both the deployment and the invocation).
The Terraform is assuming role in another account.

provider.tf:

```
terraform {
required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.33.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region                   = "us-east-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:role/AssumedRole"
    session_name = "TF"
}
}
```

The invocation happening using TF Data:

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "start-execution" {
function_name = aws_lambda_function.start-execution-lambda.function_name
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_function.start-execution-lambda]
  input         = <<JSON
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
JSON
}
```

and the assumed role has `lambda:*` permission.

unfortunately, there is a permission that I am missing, because when I am deploying the TF I get

```
╷
│ Error: AccessDeniedException:
│   status code: 403, request id: 
│
│   with data.aws_lambda_invocation.start-execution,
```

now when I grant administrator access to the assumed role I can invoke the lambda, it seems that there is another service (not lambda) that Terraform is using to invoke a Lambda function.

Comment: Are you mounting EFS by any chance?

Comment: No EFS mounting

Comment: @David any chance you could run TF_DEBUG=trace terraform apply and provide the full permissions error? If your lambda function is encrypted, you will need kms perms added to your role.

Comment: @ArpitJain Please do not post code in the comments. If you feel that is an answer, post it as such.

Comment: @marcincuber TF_DEBUG=trace doesn't give a thing but TF_LOG=DEBUG opens the terraform logs but the logs are not informative enough. + I have kms:* on all resources in the role permissions.

Comment: @ArpitJain to invoke the lambda with URL I should create an API gw, something that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Instead, You can use Lambda function URL. A function URL is a dedicated HTTP(S) endpoint for your Lambda function. You can invoke your function through its HTTP(S) endpoint.

Comment: @ArpitJain I am trying to avoid creating an endpoint and go serverless

Comment: Can you post the policy of the role? Because if you grant admin access to the policy of the assumed role, that means it's an issue with the policy, not that there is another service accessing the lambda.

Comment: @alex067, there is an issue with the permission, and that is that I am not exposed to all of the Terraform actions and that is why I can't give the right permission. I got Action: "\*" on all of my resources, so it's must be a resource that I am not deploying, something like using KMS to use environment variables in the lambda (BTW the policy has kms:\* permission on Resources: "*")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lambda:* permission on my lambda resource

```
Action:
 - lambda:*
Resource:
 - arn:aws:lambda:Region:AccountID:function:My-function
```

when the invoke action makes an action on the lambda version and need a qualified permisssion:

```
Action:
 - lambda:*
Resource:
 - arn:aws:lambda:Region:AccountID:function:My-function:*
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).